# Write a triggerable weekly backup of a file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I want to create a script that a trigger can run weekly to back up a sheet in Drive and affix the date it ran in the filename.

I've seen how to do it when the sheet is open in posts like this: 
[Google Spreadsheet, script, backup file, subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179672/google-spreadsheet-script-backup-file-subfolder) but I don't want to have the sheet open... I just want it to do it on its own.

I'm not using DocsList, and am using the newer DriveApp class and get an error "TypeError: Cannot find function makeCopy in object FileIterator." when I run this code and can't figure out how to call that method:

```
DriveApp.getFilesByName("WarehousePrototype")
.makeCopy("WarehousePrototype" + Date() + " backup");
```

Comment: Whoops.. I was using the wrong method - this one works when running... I'll try an installable trigger and confirm it tomorrow.

`DriveApp.getFileById("Id here")
.makeCopy(DriveApp.getFileById("Id here") + Date() + " backup");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the plural **Files** in the name of the method `getFilesByName` indicates, it does not just return one file: it returns a file iterator. The reason is that file names are not unique in Drive: you could have multiple files named "WarehousePrototype".

In general, one runs a while loop with `hasNext` and calls `next` in it. But if you are sure there is exactly one file by that name, you can just call `next`:

```
DriveApp.getFilesByName("WarehousePrototype").next().makeCopy("WarehousePrototype" + Date() + " backup");
```

But getting the file by Id is easier and more reliable:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(file_id).makeCopy("WarehousePrototype" + Date() + " backup");
```